# В чём может быть ошибка?

Tags: python, telethon

В чём может быть ошибка? Думал может дело в том, что телеграм не позволяет начать диалог с пользователем по его id. Поменял везде user_id на username, ошибка не ушла

[image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в API телеграма используется `user_id` и да бот не может начинать беседу, это значит что он может слать ответ только когда получил (перехватил) сообщение от пользователя, где и узнает `user_id` обойти это никак нельзя